# FlashDevelop Errors in Sample program

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a beginner to this program, the code is

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;    
    import flash.events.Event;    
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**    
    *...    
    * @author FXDS    
    */      
    public class Main extends Sprite    
    {           
        public function Main():Void    
        {       
            if (stage) init();    
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);    
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void    
        {       
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            // entry    
            var greeting:TextField = new TextField();
        }
        greeting:text = ("Hello World");    
        greeting.x = 100;    
        greeting.y = 100;    
        addChild(greeting);    
    }

}
```

However, when I run it, the program complains with the following error :

```
\src\Main.as(23): col: 17 Error: A constructor cannot specify a return type.
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After editing your code, I see that you have another mistake, this code : `greeting:text = ("Hello World");    
        greeting.x = 100;    
        greeting.y = 100;    
        addChild(greeting); ` should be inside the `init()` function.

Comment: FACEPALM, lol, Now I see the mistake I did on the code, package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;    
    import flash.events.Event;    
    import flash.text.TextField;  Should be                                                                   package

    import flash.display.Sprite;    
    import flash.events.Event;    
    import flash.text.TextField;         Problem Resolved, Thank you a lot for your help akmozo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you have a little mistake in your code :

```
public function Main():Void { }
```

should be

```
public function Main():void { }
```

the compiler didn't know `Void` (with a capital **V**) which is different from [`void`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/specialTypes.html#void).

and to avoid that mistake in the future, you can simply write :

```
public function Main() { }
```

Hope that can help.